# I dont want my object to know about my business layer - so how to load it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop

I posted this:

[Object depending on another object - when to load its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755253/object-depending-on-another-object-when-to-load-its-properties)

After reading this and researching some more I've come to realize that lazy loading would be ideal for my situation.  However, some background info.  The class I posted `Department` gets its properties data from a database (Sql Server 2k5).  Its your typical setup:

`Front End->BOL->DAL`

So I wanted to keep my `Department` class basically just hold information pertinent to it.  I did not / do not want to expose my business object class to this class.  So how would I fill my department object without having to make a call to my business object layer.

I think code would help:

```
public class Employee 
 { 
   public int ID { get; set; } 
   public string FirstName { get; set; } 
   public Department d { get; set; }  //todo: implement lazy load in get.
   public Employee(int ID, string FirstName) 
       { 
         this.ID = ID; 
         this.FirstName = FirstName; 
       } 
 } 


class Department 
 { 
  public string DepartmentID { get; set;} 
  public string CostCenter { get; set; } 
  public bool hasManager { get; set; } 
  //more code 
  //constructor for department 
 }
```

And then say my BOL is used to call my DAL to do something like:

```
//some bol class that simply calls the data access layer class
DAL.GetDepartments("SomeDepartment");
```

And the DAL does some code to return some data to fill a department object...

However if I lazy load my `get` property for the department then it would need to know about my `BOL` so I'd have to add a `using` statement to include that class as well.  That can't be the right way to do this...Any tips or pointers?

Comment: Why did someone vote to close?  Its a totally different topic

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do lazy loading of components, take a look at some ORM like NHibernate, EF4, etc.

To create your own lazy load solution is not a trivial task and it involves some complex concepts like dynamic proxing, maybe IL generation and other advanced topics.

Anyway, regarding your question on dependencies and use or not use your BOL from your DAL, check if you can apply [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

In my current project, almost all my domain business objects have at least two constructors.  **(1)** takes an id for that object, so that it can self-construct, pulling data from the db itself.  The other constructor **(2)** takes the data entity required for that domain object to function.  In this way, I can eager load or lazy load, whichever is best at the time.

So, if someone calls your Employee business object Department property, the property could check if it already had that.  If not, you could get the DepartmentID from the employee data, instantiate a department, and (store if and) return it.  In this way, it's easy to get whatever domain objects you need.

But you still want the eager-loading option there.  Let's say you have a Department business object, with an Employees property to return a `List(Of Employee)`.  The Employees property would directly get the data from the database, and instantiate each Employee using the *data* constructor.  So you'd have your cool Employee business objects, 80 of them, but with just one data query.

And then to take it up a notch, your objects could accept multi-layer data.  For example, you can construct an Employee with an Employee entity from the DAL, that also includes the data for the Department, Supervisor, etc.  The "ID" constructor could also get this data from the get-go.

Eventually you'll have some decisions to make about what to pre-load and what to lazy-load.  For example, maybe 90% of the time when you construct an Employee, you also need the Department data.  Then you might decide to just get the Department data when you construct an employee using the EmployeeID constructor.  But the, say, supervisor data is only used 8% of the time.  You might decide to always lazy load that.

Comment: I understand all of this, this isn't my question exactly.  My question is I don't want to call my Business Object layer within my Department class.  I hope that makes sense, my regular objects like `Employee` or `Department` should not have any knowledge of the workings of my `DAL` class.  So let us assume I have an instance of an employee and no instance of a department just yet.  If I lazy load and check that `dept == null` that is the department is null in the employees classes department property then it means I need to load the department.  But here is the issue...

Comment: (continued...) the issue is how will I load the department object inside of my employees class since I do not want my employee to call the business object layer.  It shouldn't have to.  According to the rules of object oriented programming my classes should be loosely coupled.  So how can I load my department property?

Comment: Just to try to get on the same page, you consider your example Employee/Department classes to be DAL classes?  And your DAL classes would be able to lazy load each other?

See, this can all be done a lot of different ways.  DeveloperA might have classes he calls Repository classes, and I could say no they aren't Repository classes because they handle caching.  My classes that handle data AND caching are up in by business layer, called "manager" classes.  DeveloperA responds "no, these are *smart* repositories . . ."  See, I was thinking of your examples as business objects!

Comment: (continued..) So, it's easy to have a muddled conversation, since we all have different assumptions/patterns/recentTerminology.  Sometimes in your description, it seems you consider Department (for example) a business object, and sometimes a DAL object.  Maybe prefix your class names with *b* or *d*.  *bDepartment* is a business object representing a department, *dDepartment* is a straight data class.  Do you have repository classes that serve up data objects to (and accept them from) your business layer?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, obviously, it can't be done.  Either you're going to have to let your business objects know about your data layer (make sure to use DI if you go this route) or you can't lazy load from within the business class.  A happy medium might be to create a service class that knows about both DAL workings and your business layer and knows how to load and create business objects. Of course, as Juanma stated, ORMs were built to do this kind of thing.